# Why Won't This MySQL Command Work

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with using an old MySQL command from a website.

```
INSERT INTO
       users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
       '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
       NOW(),   
       0);
```

It returns with this error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_name']) . "',
       '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
       '" . mys' at line 3
```

The article on the website was from May of 2010 so that might be a reason why it isn't working.  Here is the website:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188.  If you need anymore information I will edit this question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sql from that tutorial.  Perhaps you should post the actual code exactly as you have it.  The tutorial is creating a variable in php - if you had written it the same as the author your db would never be seeing the `$_POST` variables - instead the values of those would be concatenated into the query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords with just SHA1 applied.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Unless you use prepared statements you're one mistake away from a giant SQL injection hole.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes within your values (after each **POST[**).

```
INSERT INTO
       users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[''user_name'']) . "',
       '" . sha1($_POST[''user_pass'']) . "',
       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[''user_email'']) . "',
       NOW(),   
       0);
```

Comment: `$_POST[''user_name'']`??  You sure about that or is this a typo?

Comment: @billynoah I'm with you. This makes no sense at all.